# Installation of MediaWiki Vagrant - error logs

Tags: vagrant, mediawiki, vagrant-provision, mediawiki-installation

I try to install MediaWiki Vagrant. Also, I follow [this page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki-Vagrant).

I'm on a very new Ubuntu 16.04 installation and I've got this error message :

```
==> default: Error: /usr/local/bin/multiversion-install /vagrant/mediawiki --wiki wiki --dbname wiki --dbpass wikipassword --dbuser wikiadmin --pass vagrant --scriptpath /w --server http://dev.wiki.local.wmftest.net:8080 --confpath /vagrant/settings.d/wikis/wiki  wiki Admin
==> default:  returned 1 instead of one of [0]
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Wiki[devwiki]/Exec[wiki_setup]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /usr/local/bin/multiversion-install /vagrant/mediawiki --wiki wiki --dbname wiki --dbpass wikipassword --dbuser wikiadmin --pass vagrant --scriptpath /w --server http://dev.wiki.local.wmftest.net:8080 --confpath /vagrant/settings.d/wikis/wiki  wiki Admin
==> default:  returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

Here are all my logs :

```
cywil@cywil-GT70-2OC-2OD:~$ cd vagrant
cywil@cywil-GT70-2OC-2OD:~/vagrant$ ./setup.sh

You're all set! Simply run `vagrant up` to boot your new environment.

(Or try `vagrant config --list` to see what else you can tweak.)
cywil@cywil-GT70-2OC-2OD:~/vagrant$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'debian/contrib-jessie64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8080 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 4430 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.36
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /home/cywil/vagrant
    default: /vagrant/logs => /home/cywil/vagrant/logs
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

==> default: Machine 'default' has a post `vagrant up` message. This is a message
==> default: from the creator of the Vagrantfile, and not from Vagrant itself:
==> default: 
==> default: Vanilla Debian box. See https://atlas.hashicorp.com/debian/ for help and bug reports
cywil@cywil-GT70-2OC-2OD:~/vagrant$ vagrant roles list
Available roles:

  abusefilter                inputbox                   restbase                
  accountinfo                interwiki                  revisionslider          
  analytics                  invitesignup               sal                     
  antispam                   jsduck                     sandboxlink             
  antispoof                  jsonconfig                 scholarships            
  apex                       kafka                      score                   
  apparmor                   kartographer               scribunto               
  articleplaceholder         kartographerwv             securepoll              
  babel                      keystone                   semanticextraspecialproperties
  betafeatures               l10nupdate                 semanticmediawiki       
  buggy                      labeledsectiontransclusion   semanticresultformats   
  campaigns                  langwikis                  semantictitle           
  cassandra                  ldapauth                   sentry                  
  categorytree               liquidthreads              shorturl                
  centralauth                livingstyleguide           simple_miser            
  centralnotice              lockdown                   simple_performant       
  checkuser                  loginnotify                sitematrix              
  cirrussearch               maps                       spark                   
  cite                       massaction                 statsd                  
  citoid                     massmessage                striker                 
  cldr                       math                       svg                     
  codeeditor                 mathoid                    swift                   
  cologneblue                mathsearch                 templatedata            
  commons                    memcached                  templatesandbox         
  commons_datasets           mleb                       templatestyles          
  commonsmetadata            mobileapp                  testwiki                
  confirmedit                mobilecontentservice       textextracts            
  contactpage                mobilefrontend             three_d                 
  contenttranslation         modern                     throttleoverride        
  disableaccount             molhandler                 thumb_on_404            
  disambiguator            * monobook                   thumbor                 
  doublewiki                 multimedia                 tidy                    
  easytimeline               multimediaviewer           timedmediahandler       
  echo                       navigationtiming           timeless                
  education                  newsletter                 titleblacklist          
  elk                        newusermessage             torblock                
  emailauth                  notebook                   translate               
  embedvideo                 nuke                       uls                     
  eventbus                   oathauth                   uploadslink             
  eventlogging               oauth                      uploadwizard            
  externalstore              oauthauthentication        urlgetparameters        
  featuredfeeds              oozie                      urlshortener            
  fileannotations            openbadges                 usermerge               
  flaggedrevs                ores                       variables               
  flow                       pageassessments            varnish                 
  fss                        pagedtiffhandler           vectorbeta              
  fundraising                pageimages                 vipsscaler              
  gadgets                    pagetriage                 visualeditor            
  gadgets2                   pageviewinfo               warnings_as_errors      
  geodata                    parserfunctions            widgets                 
  geodata_elastic            parsoid                    wikibase_repo           
  geshi                      payments                   wikidata                
  gettingstarted             pdfhandler                 wikidatapagebanner      
  globalblocking             performanceinspector       wikidiff2               
  globalcssjs                phabricator                wikieditor              
  globalusage                phptags                    wikigrok                
  globaluserpage             phragile                   wikihiero               
  gpgmail                    pipeescape                 wikilove                
  graph                      poem                       wikimediaevents         
  graphoid                   poolcounter                wikimediaflow           
  greystuff                  popups                     wikimediaincubator      
  guidedtour                 private                    wikimediamaintenance    
  gwtoolset                  proofreadpage              wikimediamessages       
  hadoop                     psr3                       wikimetrics             
  headertabs                 questycaptcha              wikispeech              
  hive                       quicksurveys               wikitech                
  https                      quips                      xanalytics              
  hue                        quiz                       xhprofgui               
  iabot                      raita                      youtube                 
  iegreview                  relatedarticles            zend                    
  imagemetrics               renameuser                 zero                    

Roles marked with '*' are enabled.
Note that roles enabled by dependency are not marked.
Use `vagrant roles enable` & `vagrant roles disable` to customize.
cywil@cywil-GT70-2OC-2OD:~/vagrant$ vagrant roles enable monobook
Ok. Run `vagrant provision` to apply your changes.
cywil@cywil-GT70-2OC-2OD:~/vagrant$ vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: lsb_check...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20170425-9233-r1b890.sh
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with site.pp...
==> default: Info: Loading facts
==> default: Notice: Compiled catalog for mediawiki-vagrant.dev in environment production in 4.18 seconds
==> default: Info: Applying configuration version '1493114917.f0b87099'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Npm/Exec[npm_set_cache_dir]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Wiki[devwiki]/Exec[wiki_setup]/returns: Could not open input file: /vagrant/mediawiki/maintenance/install.php
==> default: Error: /usr/local/bin/multiversion-install /vagrant/mediawiki --wiki wiki --dbname wiki --dbpass wikipassword --dbuser wikiadmin --pass vagrant --scriptpath /w --server http://dev.wiki.local.wmftest.net:8080 --confpath /vagrant/settings.d/wikis/wiki  wiki Admin
==> default:  returned 1 instead of one of [0]
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Wiki[devwiki]/Exec[wiki_setup]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /usr/local/bin/multiversion-install /vagrant/mediawiki --wiki wiki --dbname wiki --dbpass wikipassword --dbuser wikiadmin --pass vagrant --scriptpath /w --server http://dev.wiki.local.wmftest.net:8080 --confpath /vagrant/settings.d/wikis/wiki  wiki Admin
==> default:  returned 1 instead of one of [0]
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Wiki[devwiki]/Exec[wiki_include_extra_settings]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Wiki[devwiki]/Exec[wiki_include_extra_settings]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Wiki[devwiki]/Exec[wiki_copy_LocalSettings]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Wiki[devwiki]/Exec[wiki_copy_LocalSettings]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Ready_service/Systemd::Service[mediawiki-ready]/File[/lib/systemd/system/mediawiki-ready.service]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Ready_service/Systemd::Service[mediawiki-ready]/File[/lib/systemd/system/mediawiki-ready.service]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Ready_service/Systemd::Service[mediawiki-ready]/Exec[systemd reload for mediawiki-ready]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Ready_service/Systemd::Service[mediawiki-ready]/Exec[systemd reload for mediawiki-ready]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Ready_service/Systemd::Service[mediawiki-ready]/Service[mediawiki-ready]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Ready_service/Systemd::Service[mediawiki-ready]/Service[mediawiki-ready]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Hhvm::Fcgi/Systemd::Service[hhvm]/File[/etc/systemd/system/hhvm.service.d]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Hhvm::Fcgi/Systemd::Service[hhvm]/File[/etc/systemd/system/hhvm.service.d]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Hhvm::Fcgi/Systemd::Service[hhvm]/File[/etc/systemd/system/hhvm.service.d/puppet-override.conf]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Hhvm::Fcgi/Systemd::Service[hhvm]/File[/etc/systemd/system/hhvm.service.d/puppet-override.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Hhvm::Fcgi/Systemd::Service[hhvm]/Exec[systemd reload for hhvm]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Hhvm::Fcgi/Systemd::Service[hhvm]/Exec[systemd reload for hhvm]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Hhvm::Fcgi/Systemd::Service[hhvm]/Service[hhvm]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Hhvm::Fcgi/Systemd::Service[hhvm]/Service[hhvm]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Group[devwiki_suppress]/Mediawiki::Settings[devwiki_suppress_group]/File[/vagrant/settings.d/wikis/wiki/settings.d/puppet-managed/10-devwiki_suppress_group.php]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Group[devwiki_suppress]/Mediawiki::Settings[devwiki_suppress_group]/File[/vagrant/settings.d/wikis/wiki/settings.d/puppet-managed/10-devwiki_suppress_group.php]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Exec[update_all_databases]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Exec[update_all_databases]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::User[admin_user_in_steward_suppress_on_wiki]/Mediawiki::Maintenance[mediawiki_user_Admin_wiki]/Exec[mediawiki_user_Admin_wiki]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::User[admin_user_in_steward_suppress_on_wiki]/Mediawiki::Maintenance[mediawiki_user_Admin_wiki]/Exec[mediawiki_user_Admin_wiki]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::User[admin_user_in_steward_suppress_on_wiki]/Mediawiki::Maintenance[mediawiki_user_Admin_wiki_steward,suppress]/Exec[mediawiki_user_Admin_wiki_steward,suppress]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::User[admin_user_in_steward_suppress_on_wiki]/Mediawiki::Maintenance[mediawiki_user_Admin_wiki_steward,suppress]/Exec[mediawiki_user_Admin_wiki_steward,suppress]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Import::Text[Main_Page]/Mediawiki::Maintenance[add page devwiki/Main_Page]/Exec[add page devwiki/Main_Page]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Import::Text[Main_Page]/Mediawiki::Maintenance[add page devwiki/Main_Page]/Exec[add page devwiki/Main_Page]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Import::Text[Template:Main_Page]/Mediawiki::Maintenance[add page devwiki/Template:Main_Page]/Exec[add page devwiki/Template:Main_Page]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki/Mediawiki::Import::Text[Template:Main_Page]/Mediawiki::Maintenance[add page devwiki/Template:Main_Page]/Exec[add page devwiki/Template:Main_Page]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/File[/etc/default/jobrunner]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/File[/etc/default/jobrunner]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/File[/etc/jobrunner.json]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/File[/etc/jobrunner.json]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/File[/etc/logrotate.d/mediawiki_jobrunner]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/File[/etc/logrotate.d/mediawiki_jobrunner]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/File[/etc/logrotate.d/mediawiki_jobchron]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/File[/etc/logrotate.d/mediawiki_jobchron]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Git::Clone[mediawiki/services/jobrunner]/File[/vagrant/srv/jobrunner]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Git::Clone[mediawiki/services/jobrunner]/File[/vagrant/srv/jobrunner]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Git::Clone[mediawiki/services/jobrunner]/Exec[git_clone_mediawiki/services/jobrunner]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Git::Clone[mediawiki/services/jobrunner]/Exec[git_clone_mediawiki/services/jobrunner]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Service::Gitupdate[jobrunner]/File[/etc/mw-vagrant/services/jobrunner.conf]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Service::Gitupdate[jobrunner]/File[/etc/mw-vagrant/services/jobrunner.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Service::Gitupdate[jobchron]/File[/etc/mw-vagrant/services/jobchron.conf]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Service::Gitupdate[jobchron]/File[/etc/mw-vagrant/services/jobchron.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobrunner]/File[/lib/systemd/system/jobrunner.service]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobrunner]/File[/lib/systemd/system/jobrunner.service]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobrunner]/Exec[systemd reload for jobrunner]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobrunner]/Exec[systemd reload for jobrunner]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobrunner]/Service[jobrunner]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobrunner]/Service[jobrunner]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobchron]/File[/lib/systemd/system/jobchron.service]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobchron]/File[/lib/systemd/system/jobchron.service]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobchron]/Exec[systemd reload for jobchron]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobchron]/Exec[systemd reload for jobchron]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobchron]/Service[jobchron]: Dependency Exec[wiki_setup] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Mediawiki::Jobrunner/Systemd::Service[jobchron]/Service[jobchron]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
==> default: Notice: Finished catalog run in 5.22 seconds
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

What can I do ?

Many thanks by advanced for your answers !

Cyril

Comment: I haven't got a "maintenance" folder in my "mediawiki" folder :
[logs](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/izWdUVsyh4R~y-hK3wtxS15M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=)

Comment: Some kind of git checkout failure, or maybe you accidentally deleted it. If your VM does not contain anything valuable, just reinstall it from scratch. Otherwise, you could do a `git reset --hard` in the `/vagrant/mediawiki` guest directory to restore the files, then run `vagrant provision`.